# How to change column headers into rows values whic maps to multiple values in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I have a table as below :[image]

I am trying to take out the total number of test cases passed failed skipped or pending for last three months and I used this below query :

```
SELECT unnest(array[to_char(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months', 'Month'), to_char(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months', 'Month'), to_char(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months', 'Month')]) AS metric,
unnest(array['passed', 'failed', 'pending', 'skipped']) AS "Values",   
unnest(array[total_test_cases_passed, total_test_cases_failed, total_test_cases_pending, total_test_cases_skipped]) AS "Count" 
FROM batch_details 
Where end_time >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3 month' and end_time < date_trunc('month', now()) 
ORDER BY "Values";
```

but this query is not showing the full result, it shows for jun only for failed and passed, and for april it shows pending ones only.
something like below :

[image]

Could anyone please help me with the query so it displays all the results. I am actually using this query in grafana to craete a graph, where x axis will be months and y axis will show the total number of test cases passed, failed, skipped, pending for three months

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, I believe the missing point is that you need to aggregate the data at the right level before unpivoting.

So if you first aggregate the data with

```
select 
    date_trunc('month', end_time) as month,
    (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_passed]))[2] as total_test_cases_passed, 
    (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_failed]))[2] as total_test_cases_failed,
    (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_pending]))[2] as total_test_cases_pending,
    (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_skipped]))[2] as total_test_cases_skipped
from batch_details
Where end_time >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3 month' and end_time < date_trunc('month', now()) 
group by date_trunc('month', end_time)
```

then you can correctly unpivot. The whole query is

```
with overall_sum_per_month as(
    select 
        date_trunc('month', end_time) as month,
        (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_passed]))[2] as total_test_cases_passed, 
        (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_failed]))[2] as total_test_cases_failed,
        (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_pending]))[2] as total_test_cases_pending,
        (MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_skipped]))[2] as total_test_cases_skipped
    from batch_details
    Where modality = 'CT' and end_time >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3 month' and end_time < date_trunc('month', now()) 
    group by date_trunc('month', end_time)
)
select month,
    unnest(array['passed', 'failed', 'pending', 'skipped']),
    unnest(array[total_test_cases_passed, total_test_cases_failed, total_test_cases_pending, total_test_cases_skipped]) AS "Count" 
FROM overall_sum_per_month;
```

**Edit**: I changed the above queries as per below discussion if you need to have the last figure of the month instead of the `sum` and filter for `modality=CT`

Comment: then substitute the `sum` lines with
```(MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_passed]))[2]```

Comment: Thanks alot @Ftisiot works like a charm, but instead of sum i want the latest data in every category like passed, failed skipped pending. could you please help me with that and also I need to add condition where modality = 'CT'

Comment: Adding the condition in the above query is just a `WHERE` statement away

Comment: Hi I made the changes , but now it says that the column total_test_cases_passed does not exists I am sending the query as answer as it is not getting accepted in comments

Comment: Thanks alooooooot working great just a last bit, currently I can see the full date how can I see only the month like  date_trunc('month', end_time) as month, => this returns full date , but I want to see month for which we can use Extract (month from) => but this will only return month number not the name. How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

with overall_sum_per_month as(
select
date_trunc('month', end_time) as month,
(MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_passed]))[2],
(MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_failed]))[2],
(MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_pending]))[2],
(MAX(ARRAY[extract(epoch from end_time), total_test_cases_skipped]))[2]
from batch_details
Where modality = 'CT' and  end_time >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3 month' and end_time < date_trunc('month', now())
group by date_trunc('month', end_time)
)
select month,
unnest(array['passed', 'failed', 'pending', 'skipped']),
unnest(array[total_test_cases_passed, total_test_cases_failed, total_test_cases_pending, total_test_cases_skipped]) AS "Count"
FROM overall_sum_per_month;